# Vessel for Susano’o?

Tags: naruto

During the final battle between Naruto and Sasuke, Kurama says

> [Sasuke] might just become the next vessel for Susano'o.

Throughout the series, Masashi has never mentioned a "vessel" for Susano'o.

Was this just a translation error; what did he mean by this?

Comment: Can you state the chapter number or episode you're referring to?

Comment: Manga chapter 696

Comment: Speculation only - apparently the tailed beasts aren't the only spirits capable of inhabiting a host in the narutoverse

Comment: I think that is a translation error. The source that I read have Kurama said, "And now with the Gedo Statue gone, he is putting them all into Susano'o".

Comment: Maybe it was like, " Sasuke might make his Susano'o the next vessel"(for the Tailed Beasts.)

Answer (score 1):

That's clearly a translation error. from what I read, Kurama says that he's merging the disseminated chakra into one.And since there is no Gedo Statue, he's using the Susano'o as the receiving vessel.
[image: The manga panel from volume 696 of Naruto's manga]